# How is best to setup MySQL Relational Database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I've been working on improving a ticket system I made sometime ago and don't know the best way to store ticket updates. Some background- each ticket can be updated with some text, status can be updated and can be assigned to other people.

The tickets table looks roughly like this:

```
tickets:

|tk_id|tk_status|tk_opened_by|tk_assigned|tk_room|tk_problem|tk_date|tk_time|
|-----|---------|------------|-----------|-------|----------|-------|-------|
```

Currently when a ticket is updated (either with a comment, status change or assignment) different tables are used for this. They are as follows:

```
tk_update:

|update_id|tk_id|user_id|comment|date|time|
|---------|-----|-------|-------|----|----|


tk_status:

|status_update_id|tk_id|user_id|status|comment|date|time|
|----------------|-----|-------|------|-------|----|----|


tk_assign:

|assign_id|tk_id|user_id|assigned_to|comment|date|time|
|---------|-----|-------|-----------|-------|----|----|
```

This current set up means pulling data from the 3 tables for a ticket and then ordering them before displaying the data on the webpage. I'm thinking of changing the setup to be as follows:

```
tickets:

|tk_id|tk_status|tk_opened_by|tk_assigned|tk_room|tk_problem|tk_date|tk_time|
|-----|---------|------------|-----------|-------|----------|-------|-------|

tk_updates:

|update_id|tk_id|user_id|assigned_to|status|comment|date|time|
|---------|-----|-------|-----------|------|-------|----|----|
```

That way there is only one table containing all of the updates. My only concern with this is that when a comment update is added the status and assigned_to data will have to be duplicated. Are there any better ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the added value to calling your columns `tk_*` ?

Comment: The database has more tables relating to other applications and user control. I think it's just how it was setup- no real value added

Comment: Why do you split date and time into 2 separate attributes? Why do you need to display all the data at the same time?

Comment: I split it so I can easily get everything from a set date for analysis in other areas of the application. I need to display all data for a ticket when a user views that ticket so they can see what has happened with the ticket in date/time order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_id`,`assigned_to`,`status` can be moved to `tickets` table which shows the current status of the ticket.
Also, instead of `tk_date`, it can be `tk_opened_date`, and `tk_updated_date`.

`update_id` can be primary key with auto increment for `tk_updates` table keeping `tk_id` as foreign key.
Instead of columns as `assigned_to`/`status`/, you can have columns say `assigned`, `status` which can be updated for every change in any of these values.

This table would show the history of the ticket.

#### Example:

```
tickets:

|tk_id|tk_status|tk_opened_by|tk_assigned|tk_room |tk_problem|tk_opened_date|tk_updated_date|
|-----|---------|------------|-----------|--------|----------|--------------|---------------|
|123  |CLOSED   |john        |wren       |somedata|somedata  |01/08/2016    |08/08/2016     |

tk_updates:

|update_id|tk_id|user_id|assigned|status    |comment                  |date      |time    |
|---------|-----|-------|--------|----------|-------------------------|----------|--------|
|1        |123  |AAA    |null    |open      |opened ticket            |01/08/2016|00:00:00|
|2        |123  |AAA    |John    |open      |ticket assigned to John  |01/08/2016|00:00:00|
|3        |123  |AAA    |John    |inprogress|now in inprogress        |01/08/2016|00:00:00|
|4        |123  |BBB    |Wren    |inprogress|John assigned to Wren    |01/08/2016|00:00:00|
|5        |123  |BBB    |Wren    |closed    |fixed, closing now       |08/08/2016|00:00:00|
```

Every ticket will have one only row with current status and all details in `updates` table.

Whenever there is an update, a new row has to be inserted in `updates` table.  You can have a trigger to update values of `assigned_to`/`status`/`tk_updated_Date` in  `ticket` table whenever there is a new row insert in `updates` table.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the approach I'm going to take